# How to automate triggering of a deploy hook at a specified time

Tags: continuous-integration, nuxt.js, github-actions, vercel, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt project where I scrape data in the server and send it back to the client on request.

The app is SSG so the scraping happens at build time. The data changes once every 12 hours.

I deployed it on vercel and it's working correctly but don't know how to setup an automation
to trigger vercel deploy hooks to redeploy the app with the new data.

I prefer to do it with GitHub Actions if it's possible so that all the projects is in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/every-12-hours) to find out how to make a cronjob every 12 hours aka `0 */12 * * *`.
Then, you can schedule it in your Github actions like the following

```yaml
on:
  # Triggers the workflow every 12 hours
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 */12 * * *"
```

Check this [dev article](https://dev.to/anshuman_bhardwaj/free-cron-jobs-with-github-actions-31d6) or the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule).

Comment: This worked, Thanks! I used https://github.com/wei/curl in the workflow for anyone who might need this